# convert json format to other array type json format

Tags: php, json

I have a json format and want to convert this to my customized format. Please help me for this conversion using PHP. Please help me out, how can i construct the above mentioned JSON array format. Here is my format:

```
{
"success": true,
"code": 601,
"u_id": "9",
"h_id": "5",
"data": [{
    "mp_cat": "Conveyance",
    "mp_id": "5",
    "mp_rating": "4",
    "mp_price": "630.00"
}, {
    "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
    "mp_id": "3",
    "mp_rating": "4",
    "mp_price": "104.55"
}, {
    "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
    "mp_id": "4",
    "mp_rating": "3",
    "mp_price": "450.00"
}]
}
```

And want this kind of format:

```
 {
"success": true,
"code": 601,
"u_id": "9",
"h_id": "5",
"category": [{
    "Name": "Food & Drinks",
    "data": [{
        "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
        "mp_id": "3",
        "mp_rating": "4",
        "mp_price": "104.55"
    }, {
        "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
        "mp_id": "4",
        "mp_rating": "3",
        "mp_price": "450.00"
    }]
}, {
    "Name": "Conveyance",
    "data": [{
        "mp_cat": "Conveyance",
        "mp_id": "5",
        "mp_rating": "4",
        "mp_price": "630.00"
    }]
}]
}
```

Comment: From where you are getting this json?

Comment: getting form a mysql query

Comment: Will you share that code @deepakbhardwaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use simple foreach loop to construct your data, or reformat json.
Halve a look on below solution:

```
$json = '{
"success": true,
"code": 601,
"u_id": "9",
"h_id": "5",
"data": [{
    "mp_cat": "Conveyance",
    "mp_id": "5",
    "mp_rating": "4",
    "mp_price": "630.00"
}, {
    "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
    "mp_id": "3",
    "mp_rating": "4",
    "mp_price": "104.55"
}, {
    "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
    "mp_id": "4",
    "mp_rating": "3",
    "mp_price": "450.00"
}]
}';

$json_array = json_decode($json, true);
$new_array = array();
$category_array = array();
foreach($json_array as $key => $array){
    if($key == 'data'){
        foreach($array as $a){
            $category_array[$a['mp_cat']]['name']= $a['mp_cat'];
            $category_array[$a['mp_cat']]['data'][]= $a;
        }
    } else{
        $new_array[$key] = $array;
    }
}

$new_array['category'] = array_values($category_array);
echo json_encode($new_array);
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "code": 601,
    "u_id": "9",
    "h_id": "5",
    "category": [{
        "name": "Conveyance",
        "data": [{
            "mp_cat": "Conveyance",
            "mp_id": "5",
            "mp_rating": "4",
            "mp_price": "630.00"
        }]
    }, {
        "name": "Food & Drinks",
        "data": [{
            "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
            "mp_id": "3",
            "mp_rating": "4",
            "mp_price": "104.55"
        }, {
            "mp_cat": "Food & Drinks",
            "mp_id": "4",
            "mp_rating": "3",
            "mp_price": "450.00"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: How to convert this JSON [{"label":"Food & Drinks","data":"2"},{"label":"Lifestyle","data":"1"}]  to [["Food & Drinks", 2],["Lifestyle", 1]] using php

Comment: please post a new question on SO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269178/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array-in-php