# how to convert json string to array in php?

Tags: php, json

I have a json format and want to convert this to my customized format. Please help me for this conversion using PHP. Please help me out, how can i construct the above mentioned JSON array format. Here is my format:

```
 [{"label":"Food & Drinks","data":"2"},{"label":"Lifestyle","data":"1"}]
```

And want result in this format:

```
[["Food & Drinks", 2],["Lifestyle", 1]]
```

Comment: `json_decode($json, true)`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ typo.. :)

Comment: I know json decode. I want to customize this format to other format.

Comment: You just want to ignore the keys. I guess you want to use in some javascript.

Comment: Please provide some code where you can show what you have done until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below solution:

```
$json = '[{"label":"Food & Drinks","data":"2"},{"label":"Lifestyle","data":"1"}]';

$json_array = json_decode($json, true);

$new_array = array();

foreach($json_array as $arr){
    $new_array[] = array_values($arr);
}

print_r($new_array);

echo json_encode($new_array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Food & Drinks
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lifestyle
            [1] => 1
        )

)
[["Food & Drinks","2"],["Lifestyle","1"]]
```

for more detail have alook at [PHP: json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

- First use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to decode the json string
- Then use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to apply a callback function([`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) in this case) to each element of the given array

So your code should be like this:

```
// suppose $json is your json string
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$newArr = array_map('array_values', $arr);

// display $newArr array
var_dump($newArr);
```

Here `$newArr` is your desired array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
$result = array();
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($array); $i++){
    $result[] = array_values($array[$i]);
}
```

$result will be your expected result

Answer (score 0):

Version that casts 'data' value to int

```
$json = '[{"label":"Food & Drinks","data":"2"},{"label":"Lifestyle","data":"1"}]';

$output = json_encode(array_map(function($v) {
    $v['data'] = (int) $v['data'];
    return array_values($v);
}, json_decode($json, true)));

// ["Food & Drinks",2],["Lifestyle",1]]
echo $output;
```

If int isn't needed

```
$output = json_encode(array_map('array_values', json_decode($json, true)));
```