# How to make JSON data as Array in PHP?

Tags: laravel

Am trying to output an array from this JSON response

```
[
    [
        {
            "nombre": "TSU EN TICME",
            "nivel": 1,
            "numero": 4,
            "alias": "TICME",
            "inicio": "2016-09-02",
            "fin": "2019-09-26"
        },
        {
            "nombre": "TSU EN CONTADURIA",
            "nivel": 1,
            "numero": 6,
            "alias": "CONT",
            "inicio": "2016-09-03",
            "fin": "2019-09-27"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: That's a lot of downvotes for a brand new user. Maybe instead of simply downvoting, ya'll could provide some guidance that would actually be useful. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Because it shows no research, this question was asked countless times

Comment: @CaddyDZ, I'm not saying the question doesn't merritt downvotes. I'm saying it's not particularly helpful for a brand new user to see a bunch of downvotes on their question without any explanation as to why.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert json string to array in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35269178/how-to-convert-json-string-to-array-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `json_decode` ([see docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) function to take the data you have and parse it into a php array.

```
$array = json_decode('[[{"nombre":"TSU EN TICME","nivel":1,"numero":4,"alias":"TICME","inicio":"2016-09-02","fin":"2019-09-26"},{"nombre":"TSU EN CONTADURIA","nivel":1,"numero":6,"alias":"CONT","inicio":"2016-09-03","fin":"2019-09-27"}]]');
```

Keep in mind, Laravel is not a programming language. It is a PHP framework. That's why you won't find this in the Laravel documentation. When you are looking for something like this, you should be searching the PHP documentation.

Comment: How can I reproduce it in a foreach or in a for?

Comment: Here you go: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @RaymundoAparicioOlarte, if this answer solved your problem, please upvote it, and mark it as "accepted" (checkmark), so that it can help other users in the future. Thanks!